# displaying the mismatch into the excel using php

Tags: excel, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, export-to-csv

I am importing the the csv data into the database, records which are not matching with the dtdc are the mismatch are mismatched records . I am exporting those records into excel.Below is the else condition which we are taking the mismatch records

```
else{
    $mismarchrows_dtdc[] = $row['Postcode'];
    $mismatchcount_dtdc = $mismatchcount_dtdc+1;    
}
```

Here i am writing the mismatched records into excel

```
$fileName_dtdc = 'uploads/csv/already_exist_customer_dtdc-'.time().'.xls';
$fp = fopen($fileName_dtdc, 'w');
$newLineSeparator = "\r\n";
$line1_dtdc = 'postcode'.$newLineSeparator;
fwrite($fp,$line1_dtdc);
foreach($mismarchrows_dtdc as $mrow){
    $line2_dtdc = $mrow;
    fwrite($fp,$line2_dtdc);
}
```

now only one column called postcode is only exported into excel, but i 5 more columns like firstname,lastname,middlename in to the excel with data

I tried by keeping like this, But coming in only one column

```
else{
    $mismarchrows_dtdc[] = $row['Postcode'];
    $mismarchrows_dtdc1[] .= $row['State'];
    $mismatchcount_dtdc = $mismatchcount_dtdc + 1;  
}
```

can anyone help with this !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact needs, but maybe this will help?

```
$csv_lines = array();
foreach($mismarchrows_dtdc as $mrow) {
    $keys = array_keys($mrow);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $data[] = $mrow[$key];
    }

    $csv_lines[] = implode(',',$data);
}

$fileName_dtdc = 'uploads/csv/already_exist_customer_dtdc-'.time().'.xls';

file_put_contents($fileName_dtdc,implode("\r\n",$csv_lines));
```